# Unable to load Dynamic WebTable Content Selenium in Python 3.6

Tags: python, selenium

I hope you're doing fine.

I'm having a problem extracting rows of table from website by selenium. There are 50 rows showing on website but when I **scrape** it, there are only 8. First I didn't what was the problem but after so much struggle i found the problem, but can't seem to figure out the solution.

So, the table loads content when i'm focusing on it. When i'm not focusing on other rows, the html look like this:
[Div Elements When not focused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Je72a.jpg)

```
<div class="x-grid3-row x-grid3-row-alt" style="width:1355px;height:34px;"></div>
```

But when i go to those rows, it loads the content and unload previous rows.

[Div Elements When Focused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOQLf.jpg)

```
<div class="x-grid3-row x-grid3-row-alt" style="width:1355px;height:34px;"><table class="x-grid3-row-table" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:1355px;height:34px;"><tbody><tr><td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-0 x-grid3-cell-first " style="width: 28px;text-align: center;" tabindex="0"><div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-0 x-unselectable" unselectable="on"><a href="creative.form.php?id=1767">1767</a></div></td><td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-1  x-grid3-check-col-td" style="width: 38px;" tabindex="0"><div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-1 x-unselectable" unselectable="on"><div class="x-grid3-check-col">&nbsp;</div></div></td><td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-2 " style="width: 148px;" tabindex="0"><div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-2 x-unselectable" unselectable="on"><a href="https://partner.hyaffiliates.com/afs/creative.form.php?id=1767" onmouseover="adCreativePreviewShow(1767)" onmouseout="adCreativePreviewHideDelay()"><img src="https://www.hycm.com/assets/img/home-header.jpg" vspace="0" hspace="0" border="0" width="6" height="32"></a></div><div class="x-grid3-cell-adcreative-preview-container" onmouseover="adCreativePreviewShow(1767)" onmouseout="adCreativePreviewHideDelay()" id="div_preview_creative_1767" style="visibility: hidden; "><iframe src="viewad.php?id=1767" width="120" height="600" hidden="" style="display: none !important;"></iframe></div></td><td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-3 " style="width: 68px;" tabindex="0"><div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-3 x-unselectable" unselectable="on">HTML5</div></td><td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-4 " style="width: 68px;" tabindex="0"><div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-4 x-unselectable" unselectable="on">Big<br>120x600</div></td><td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-5 " style="width: 98px;" tabindex="0"><div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-5 x-unselectable" unselectable="on">HYAffiliates / HYCM</div></td><td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-6 " style="width: 98px;" tabindex="0"><div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-6 x-unselectable" unselectable="on">RU Trading</div></td><td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-7 " style="width: 98px;" tabindex="0"><div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-7 x-unselectable" unselectable="on">en</div></td><td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-8 " style="width: 98px;" tabindex="0"><div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-8 x-unselectable" unselectable="on">AU</div></td><td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-9 " style="width: 98px;" tabindex="0"><div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-9 x-unselectable" unselectable="on">&nbsp;</div></td><td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-10 " style="width: 78px;text-align: right;" tabindex="0"><div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-10 x-unselectable" unselectable="on">1</div></td><td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-11 " style="width: 63px;text-align: right;" tabindex="0"><div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-11 x-unselectable" unselectable="on">4</div></td><td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-12 " style="width: 53px;text-align: right;" tabindex="0"><div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-12 x-unselectable" unselectable="on">0</div></td><td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-13 " style="width: 43px;text-align: right;" tabindex="0"><div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-13 x-unselectable" unselectable="on">0.00%</div></td><td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-14 " style="width: 68px;text-align: right;" tabindex="0"><div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-14 x-unselectable" unselectable="on">0</div></td><td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-15 " style="width: 93px;text-align: right;" tabindex="0"><div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-15 x-unselectable" unselectable="on">0</div></td><td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-16 x-grid3-cell-last " style="width: 83px;text-align: right;" tabindex="0"><div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-16 x-unselectable" unselectable="on">$0.00</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

As you can see, the bullets are visible now indicating it loaded all Childs now when i went/focused to those rows.

I tried this method, but only give me those rows which are focused:

```
tables = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'x-grid3-row')]//tr")
    print("Length: "+str(len(tables)))
    for i, table in enumerate(tables):
        data = [item.text for item in table.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[self::td or self::th]")]
```

Anyone canplease help me? Thanks in advance

Edited: Solution:

```
 tables = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'x-grid3-row')]")
    saved = []
    for table in tables:
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", table)
        data = [item.text for item in table.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[self::td or self::th]")]
        print(data)
        saved.append(data)
        time.sleep(0.5)
    print(len(saved))
```

Comment: Please don't post image.Post the html in text format.Also post your code trial what you have tried so far.SO is not about answering OP question it also uses for research purpose.

Comment: @kunduk sorry, first time, i posted it.

Answer (score 0):

I Would suggest induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `visibility_of_all_elements_located`()

```
tables=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//table[@class='x-grid3-row-table']//tr")))
print("Length: "+str(len(tables)))
for i, table in enumerate(tables):
    data = [item.text for item in table.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[self::td or self::th]")]
```

Add following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Note: If you get the same result as before then you might need to scroll the element.

Comment: Unfortunatetly same result, I researched and found something scrollIntoView() but i've no idea how to implement it.

Comment: @ahmadamin : add this before finding elements `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")`

Comment: It's of no use because webtable have its own scroll bar and even if we scroll down, then it'll unload the previous rows.

Comment: I got your point it’s lazy loading webtable and if you go down it will lost the previous one.can your url be share in public?I know other way however not sure whether that can useful here without knowing the application.

Comment: I did it :), thanks for helping me, I used scrollIntoView()